# Send UDP from separate thread

Tags: c++, c, sockets, udp

I have a program which logs state switches over UDP. I need the logging function to be as fast as possible, but know that networking is considered slow. Is there any advantage to sending the UDP data from a separate thread, or is sending UDP just a quick call, since nothing needs to be set up or waited for (assuming I pre-opened the socket)?
I am OK with it if it returns immediately, but if internally it waits for some I/O resource, it could be a problem. Does it?

Comment: platform? Linux or Windows or other?

Comment: @Eric Both, but main one is Windows. Does it matter, or this just a general "you should always mention platform"?

Comment: @baruch: Sockets vary between Windows and POSIX. The general answer to "does it block?" might be the same for both platforms, but code to prevent it from doing so might vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't sending huge amounts [and I mean megabytes every minute] of data [or extremely often] (hundreds of packets every minute), I would expect the `send` (or `write`) to be fairly quick.

The only reason it would take a long time is if you are feeding more data than the network can take, so the kernel has to wait for a free buffer-slot to become available.

As with everything related to performance, it's however always better to measure than to ask on the internet... I would expect, on a modern PC, that a `sendmsg` call is in the order of a few hundred nanoseconds for a small packet, and about one extra nanosecond per 8 bytes if the packet is more than a few dozen bytes, up to sizes of several kilobytes. When you get to hundreds of kilobytes, the timing increases by a factor of 3-10.

Answer (score 0):

It might. To prevent it from waiting, just set the socket to non-blocking.
You may be interested in seeing [how Python sets the appropriate flag](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/99795d711a40/Modules/socketmodule.c#l591).